# CORS issue with Next.js API routes and central middleware

Tags: next.js, cors

I'm building a web application using Next.js, and I'm encountering issues related to CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) when trying to access my API routes. I've implemented a central middleware to handle CORS headers, but I'm still facing problems. Here's my setup:

I have a middleware.ts file where I'm handling CORS headers centrally for my Next.js API routes.

```js
// middleware.ts

import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';

const allowedOrigins = [
    'http://localhost:8888',
    'https://example.com',
    'https://another-example.com',
    // Add more URLs as needed
];

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    if (request.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        // Handle preflight request
        const origin = request.headers.get('Origin');
        if (origin && allowedOrigins.includes(origin)) {
            const responseHeaders = new Headers()
            responseHeaders.append(
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
                'GET, POST, OPTIONS'
            )
            responseHeaders.append(
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
                'Content-Type, Authorization'
            )
            responseHeaders.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
            responseHeaders.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin)

            return new Response(null, {
                status: 200,
                headers: responseHeaders,
            })
        }
    }

    return NextResponse.next();
}
```

My me.ts API route uses this middleware to handle CORS headers.

```
// pages/api/me.ts

import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { connectToDatabase } from 'lib/connectToDatabase';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

export default async function handler(
    req: NextApiRequest,
    res: NextApiResponse
) {
    // Token handling and user data retrieval...
}
```

Despite setting up the middleware, I'm still receiving CORS-related errors when making requests from my frontend to the me.ts API route.

Error Message:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3000/api/me' from origin 'http://localhost:8888' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I've verified the following points:

The middleware.ts middleware is imported correctly and applied to my API routes.
The order of middlewares seems correct, and the CORS middleware should execute before my me.ts route handler.
I've checked the client-side code to ensure that the requests are being made correctly and including the appropriate headers.
Could there be something I'm missing or misunderstanding in the configuration of my CORS middleware and API route handler? How can I troubleshoot and resolve this CORS issue? Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should still set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. So add this line inside the second `if` statement: `response.headers.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin)`

Comment: hi, sorry, I did not put in all code, but I have `response.headers.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin)` in second if

Comment: About that `if (request.method === 'OPTIONS')` check: not all `OPTIONS` requests are preflight requests. [Such an approach can and does lead to problems.](https://jub0bs.com/posts/2023-02-08-fearless-cors/#4-categorise-requests-correctly) Rather than writing a CORS middleware from scratch (which is error-prone), why not rely on a proven CORS middleware library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> if (request.method === 'OPTIONS') {
>     // Handle preflight request
> ```

CORS headers need to be on the response to the "real" request **and** any preflight request (**not** just the preflight).

---

CORS is a common requirement and has [well-tested third party middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) which [next.js uses in their example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/api-routes-cors). I recommend switching to that instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Yes to this. Always use a proven CORS middleware library (if one is available) rather than writing a CORS middleware from scratch. CORS is more difficult that meets the eye.

Comment: The example is now outdated (no App router)